# Best way to compare/diff two big directories that are backups (by `rsync -aAX`) of a boot partition from another computer?

Tags: rsync, backup, diff, file-comparison, unison

[ EDIT:
Answered my own question.

Used `unison` and some hacky post-processing
(
copy-pasted the log output of unison,
tweaked it in my text-editor with multi-selection editing,
then did some shell script processing on that (fishshell)
)

((I've got so much more disaster recovery stuff to slog through, so I guess I'm done with *this* for now...))
]

---

So I have an SSD that used to be inside another computer,
and I put it in one of those little SATA-to-USB enclosure/adapter shell things,
mounted it as an external data drive,
and used `rsync -aAX` to copy the boot partition over into a dir on this computer, for a backup.

But then, after some other events that *probably* didn't change the contents of the original boot partition,
I made a second backup.

So now I have two dirs on this computer,
which I think are *probably* two copies of exactly the same backup,
but I want to make sure.

---

So my question is:
**What is the best way to compare/diff these two big backup directories?**

Summary of things I have considered/tried but had problems with or am unsure about:

- `diff` itself
- `rsync` "dry run" trick
- `unison` [(just thought of, but it hasn't finished running yet, due to the large size of the backups and the slow speed of my old hardware.)]

Is one of these essentially a good option?
If so, any corrections to the details of how I should go about using it?

Or are there any separate, additional options I should know about..?

---

## Details of my attempts and the results/problems:

---

### `diff`

The obvious way of doing it for "*normal*" directories would be like:
$ `diff -r dir_A dir_B`
(
or maybe $ `diff -r --no-dereference dir_A dir_B`?
I don't know; I honestly don't properly understand the function of `--no-dereference`
-- it's just something I've found got me the results I wanted in *vaguely* similar situations in the past.
)

However, the problem with using `diff` is that these dirs are of course very unusually large,
and full of "weird" files from the bootable system
(eg "character special files" and "block special file" etc).

---

### `rsync`

So it occurred to me to just use `rsync` again between them,
doing a "dry run" and seeing if it reported any changes it would make.

Like:
$ `sudo rsyncy -n -aAX dir_A dir_B --log-file=log_file`

However, it then occurred to me

- "what if there were *new* files in dir_B?"
- "would rsyncy necessarily always report that?"

So I guessed you would have to check both:
$ `sudo rsyncy -n -aAX --delete dir_A dir_B --log-file='log_file[A-to-B]'`
and
$ `sudo rsyncy -n -aAX --delete dir_B dir_A --log-file='log_file[B-to-A]'`
which is starting to feel a little suspiciously like maybe that isn't really the right tool for the job after all...?

The log files I got read:

`A-to-B`
#=>

```
2023/07/21 01:43:04 [26686] building file list  
2023/07/21 02:12:24 [26686] sent 80.58M bytes  received 292.46K bytes  45.93K bytes/sec  
2023/07/21 02:12:24 [26686] total size is 229.29G  speedup is 2,835.29 (DRY RUN)
```

`B-to-A`

```
2023/07/21 01:41:58 [26406] building file list  
2023/07/21 02:12:15 [26406] sent 80.58M bytes  received 292.50K bytes  44.49K bytes/sec  
2023/07/21 02:12:15 [26406] total size is 229.29G  speedup is 2,835.29 (DRY RUN)
```

which are (ignoring the timestamps and speed information),
annoyingly *ALMOST* the exact same:
both
`sent 80.58M bytes`

but *tiny* different received:
`received 292.46K bytes`
vs
`received 292.50K bytes`

So yeah, again, I'm feeling doubtful this `rsync` trick is really the right tool for the job...?

Maybe the correct answer really *is* like:
"
Just be patient and let `diff` run for ages to process the two huge directories.
(You can just ignore all the error messages about `special file` etc.)
"
??

---

### `unison`

[not sure yet?]

Comment: Have you consider first find different files and use `diff` only on them?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Do you mean something like use the `find` command and send its output to `diff` somehow? (Like with the `-exec` flag or something?) Or...?

Comment: I mean first to generate hash of files, then compare and filter only pairs that differ and apply `diff` only on them.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Do you have a link to a more detailed guide/tutorial for what you're talking about? Because I don't think I could concretely *implement* that solution just from that abbreviated description... it sounds somewhat tricky and complex, difficult to keep track of? (Easy to mess up if you're figuring it out for the first time, especially working with such an unwieldy amount of data while learning.) Like, is this... going through the tree of directories, creating a copy with each "leaf" file in the tree replaced with a hash of itself...? Or archiving/compressing/zipping first? Or...?

Comment: I do not have such manual, just get the idea from your question. If there is no other answer I will write a script to do the idea.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Wow, I really appreciate the offer... to the point where I'd feel kinda guilty if you went to all the trouble of writing a script for me. But I still don't think I understand what you meant well enough to write it myself... My *guess* is, in summary: For both dir `A` and `B`, use `find` with `-exec` flag to generate a copy of the dir with the actual files replaced with hashes of themselves (using `sha256sum` or `md5sum` or whatever), then use `diff` to compare those two copies with each other. Is that what you meant?

Comment: (@RomeoNinov I'm currently trying `unison` though, so maybe that'll work. *Any* solution takes a long time to run due to the massive size of the backups and the slow speed of my old hardware, so it still hasn't finished running yet.)

Comment: Read `man hardlink`, and do something like `hardlink --dry-run --verbose dir_A dir_B`.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks, that's good to learn about! However, that simply outputs nothing and never returns, and I *think* that's because (I just realized) `dir_A` and `dir_B` are actually each their own btrfs subvolume. But now that I've realized that, I'll try googling like "compare two btrfs subvolumes"...

Comment: "_I honestly don't properly understand the function of `--no-dereference`_" - if you use this flag then `diff` won't follow symbolic links (read `man diff` sometime). You will want this flag if you're comparing large trees

Comment: @roaima Thanks, sorry, I shoulda phrased it better: I know *in principle* what it does (it's obvious from the name), and I don't *think* it'd be relevant here beyond making things a bit more/less efficient (although *probably* proportionally not a large amount here?), but I don't have a good enough mental model of the details of what weird edgecases are possible to be *sure* there couldn't be some confusing/surprising to me unknown-unknown way it could matter to this...

Comment: @waltinator Sorry, I was completely wrong about the btrfs subvolume thing being relevant to `hardlink`. It just took so much longer for output to start showing up (even though it says "`--verbose`"), compared to the relatively-smaller-but-still-large dirs I tested it with first, that I thought at first it was just getting stuck doing nothing.

Comment: @waltinator also, whoops, with the trouble getting it to work at all, I missed the "flag it twice" thing. Had to restart the whole thing, heh. ("`Verbose output, explain to the user what is being done. If specified once, every hardlinked file is displayed. If specified twice, it also shows every comparison.`") ($` sudo hardlink --dry-run --verbose --verbose dir_A dir_B | tee logfile` (I assume shortens to `-nvv`, but with how big/slow/lumbering it is with these dirs and my crappy hardware, not gonna check)) But yeah, *really* thanks for the tip! I had no idea you could do something like that.

Comment: @waltinator ... annnd I just realized, I think I *also* need all: $`hardlink -nvv --respect-dir --respect-name --respect-xattrs dir_A dir_B`, but when I try to add `--minimum-size 0K` (which I *think* I also need for this?) it just seems to do nothing again? (Or should that be `--minimum-size 0`? If so, the manpage doesn't mention it... it only says plain zero is special for *maximum* size...)

Comment: Use `-n -vv` instead of `-nvv`. Option parsing is hard.

Comment: @waltinator thanks, but `-nvv` didn't seem to cause any problems. (Although I did note the manpage's (here irrelvant) warning  `-f, --respect-name : Only try to link files with the same (base)name. It’s strongly recommended to use long options rather than -f which is interpreted in a different way by other hardlink implementations.`) The *problem* was that I'm quite sure I need to set `--minimum-size` to zero to get a full compare, right? But neither `0` nor `0K` worked....

Comment: @waltinator ie, other than the duration (`15846.626002` vs `15626.745668` seconds, so like getting on to 4 or 5 hours), the log files were identical (`Mode:     dry-run`/`Method:   sha256`/`Files:    4563840`/`Linked:   0 files`/`Compared: 0 xattrs`/`Compared: 0 files`/`Saved:    0 B`) But *without* `--minimum-size`, it seemed to otherwise work great, outputting all those useful lines of rx`^(\[DryRun\] Linking|Skipped)` It's a pity, because it would otherwise seem like a really neat solution...

Comment: @waltinator Anyway, I answered my own question with unison (and some hacky shell scripting (fishshell) processing unison's logging output to make sure), so I guess I'm done with this now. (I've got so much more disaster recovery headaches to slog through still...) But yeah, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `unison`

This worked for me in the end.

Here's the output data from unison,
plus a bit of manual checking I did on it using my fishshell at the end.

---

### data from unison

$`unison dir_A dir_B`

reported a bunch of errors "`unknown file type`" for the weird stuff from the bootable system
but then a summary:

```
  0 items will be synced, 326 skipped  
  0 B to be synced from dir_A to dir_B  
  0 B to be synced from dir_B to dir_A  
  No updates to propagate  
  Synchronization complete at 07:40:11  (0 items transferred, 326 skipped, 0 failed)
```

and then a list like
(
elastic-tabspace aligned,
ordering tweaked,
and a bunch of repetitive lines removed to fit under the stackexchange limit
("`Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 56882.`")
):

```
  #  
         skipped: dev/console                               (path dir_A/dev/console                               has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/core                                  (path dir_A/dev/core                                  has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/full                                  (path dir_A/dev/full                                  has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/hda                                   (path dir_A/dev/hda                                   has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/hda1                                  (path dir_A/dev/hda1                                  has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/hda10                                 (path dir_A/dev/hda10                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/hda11                                 (path dir_A/dev/hda11                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/hda12                                 (path dir_A/dev/hda12                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/hda13                                 (path dir_A/dev/hda13                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/hda14                                 (path dir_A/dev/hda14                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/hda15                                 (path dir_A/dev/hda15                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/hda16                                 (path dir_A/dev/hda16                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/hda17                                 (path dir_A/dev/hda17                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/hda18                                 (path dir_A/dev/hda18                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/hda19                                 (path dir_A/dev/hda19                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/hda2                                  (path dir_A/dev/hda2                                  has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/event0                          (path dir_A/dev/input/event0                          has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/event1                          (path dir_A/dev/input/event1                          has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/event10                         (path dir_A/dev/input/event10                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/event11                         (path dir_A/dev/input/event11                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/event12                         (path dir_A/dev/input/event12                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/event13                         (path dir_A/dev/input/event13                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/event14                         (path dir_A/dev/input/event14                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/event15                         (path dir_A/dev/input/event15                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/event16                         (path dir_A/dev/input/event16                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/event17                         (path dir_A/dev/input/event17                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/event18                         (path dir_A/dev/input/event18                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/event19                         (path dir_A/dev/input/event19                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/js0                             (path dir_A/dev/input/js0                             has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/js1                             (path dir_A/dev/input/js1                             has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/js10                            (path dir_A/dev/input/js10                            has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/js11                            (path dir_A/dev/input/js11                            has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/js12                            (path dir_A/dev/input/js12                            has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/js13                            (path dir_A/dev/input/js13                            has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/js14                            (path dir_A/dev/input/js14                            has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/js15                            (path dir_A/dev/input/js15                            has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/js16                            (path dir_A/dev/input/js16                            has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/js17                            (path dir_A/dev/input/js17                            has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/js18                            (path dir_A/dev/input/js18                            has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/js19                            (path dir_A/dev/input/js19                            has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/keyboard                        (path dir_A/dev/input/keyboard                        has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/mice                            (path dir_A/dev/input/mice                            has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/mouse                           (path dir_A/dev/input/mouse                           has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/mouse0                          (path dir_A/dev/input/mouse0                          has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/mouse1                          (path dir_A/dev/input/mouse1                          has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/mouse10                         (path dir_A/dev/input/mouse10                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/mouse11                         (path dir_A/dev/input/mouse11                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/mouse12                         (path dir_A/dev/input/mouse12                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/mouse13                         (path dir_A/dev/input/mouse13                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/mouse14                         (path dir_A/dev/input/mouse14                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/mouse15                         (path dir_A/dev/input/mouse15                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/mouse16                         (path dir_A/dev/input/mouse16                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/mouse17                         (path dir_A/dev/input/mouse17                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/mouse18                         (path dir_A/dev/input/mouse18                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/mouse19                         (path dir_A/dev/input/mouse19                         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/input/uinput                          (path dir_A/dev/input/uinput                          has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/mem                                   (path dir_A/dev/mem                                   has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/null                                  (path dir_A/dev/null                                  has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/port                                  (path dir_A/dev/port                                  has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/ptmx                                  (path dir_A/dev/ptmx                                  has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/random                                (path dir_A/dev/random                                has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/sda                                   (path dir_A/dev/sda                                   has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/sda1                                  (path dir_A/dev/sda1                                  has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/sda10                                 (path dir_A/dev/sda10                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/sda11                                 (path dir_A/dev/sda11                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/sda12                                 (path dir_A/dev/sda12                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/sda13                                 (path dir_A/dev/sda13                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/sda14                                 (path dir_A/dev/sda14                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/sda15                                 (path dir_A/dev/sda15                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/tty                                   (path dir_A/dev/tty                                   has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/tty0                                  (path dir_A/dev/tty0                                  has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/tty1                                  (path dir_A/dev/tty1                                  has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/tty10                                 (path dir_A/dev/tty10                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/tty11                                 (path dir_A/dev/tty11                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/tty12                                 (path dir_A/dev/tty12                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/tty13                                 (path dir_A/dev/tty13                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/tty14                                 (path dir_A/dev/tty14                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/tty15                                 (path dir_A/dev/tty15                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/tty16                                 (path dir_A/dev/tty16                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/tty17                                 (path dir_A/dev/tty17                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/tty18                                 (path dir_A/dev/tty18                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/tty19                                 (path dir_A/dev/tty19                                 has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/urandom                               (path dir_A/dev/urandom                               has unknown file type)  
         skipped: dev/zero                                  (path dir_A/dev/zero                                  has unknown file type)  
  #  
         skipped: tmp/runtime-username/pulse/native         (path dir_A/tmp/runtime-username/pulse/native         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/guix/daemon-socket/socket             (path dir_A/var/guix/daemon-socket/socket             has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/anvil           (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/anvil           has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/bounce          (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/bounce          has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/defer           (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/defer           has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/discard         (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/discard         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/error           (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/error           has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/lmtp            (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/lmtp            has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/local           (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/local           has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/proxymap        (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/proxymap        has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/proxywrite      (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/proxywrite      has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/relay           (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/relay           has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/retry           (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/retry           has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/rewrite         (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/rewrite         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/scache          (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/scache          has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/smtp            (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/smtp            has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/tlsmgr          (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/tlsmgr          has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/trace           (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/trace           has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/verify          (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/verify          has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/private/virtual         (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/virtual         has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/public/cleanup          (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/public/cleanup          has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/public/flush            (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/public/flush            has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/public/pickup           (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/public/pickup           has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/public/postlog          (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/public/postlog          has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/public/qmgr             (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/public/qmgr             has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/spool/postfix/public/showq            (path dir_A/var/spool/postfix/public/showq            has unknown file type)  
         skipped: var/tmp/audacity-username/.audacity.sock  (path dir_A/var/tmp/audacity-username/.audacity.sock  has unknown file type)
```

plus a few things under home like:

```
  #  
     #  
        #  
           skipped: home/username/.cache/fontforge/python-socket                                                 (path dir_A/home/username/.cache/fontforge/python-socket                                                 has unknown file type)  
           skipped: home/username/.cache/keyring-70EDPZ/control                                                  (path dir_A/home/username/.cache/keyring-70EDPZ/control                                                  has unknown file type)  
        #  
           skipped: home/username/.copy/copyagent-overlay.socket                                                 (path dir_A/home/username/.copy/copyagent-overlay.socket                                                 has unknown file type)  
        #  
           skipped: home/username/.dropbox/command_socket                                                        (path dir_A/home/username/.dropbox/command_socket                                                        has unknown file type)  
           skipped: home/username/.dropbox/iface_socket                                                          (path dir_A/home/username/.dropbox/iface_socket                                                          has unknown file type)  
     #  
     #  
           skipped: home/username/.local/share/parcellite/fifo_c                                                 (path dir_A/home/username/.local/share/parcellite/fifo_c                                                 has unknown file type)  
           skipped: home/username/.local/share/parcellite/fifo_cmd                                               (path dir_A/home/username/.local/share/parcellite/fifo_cmd                                               has unknown file type)  
           skipped: home/username/.local/share/parcellite/fifo_p                                                 (path dir_A/home/username/.local/share/parcellite/fifo_p                                                 has unknown file type)  
     #  
           skipped: home/username/.steam/steam.pipe                                                              (path dir_A/home/username/.steam/steam.pipe                                                              has unknown file type)  
     #  
           skipped: home/username/Dropbox/.emacs.d/packages/gnupg/S.gpg-agent                                    (path dir_A/home/username/Dropbox/.emacs.d/packages/gnupg/S.gpg-agent                                    has unknown file type)  
     #  
           skipped: home/username/ax/bups/hostname/dropbox/0rolling/Dropbox/.emacs.d/packages/gnupg/S.gpg-agent  (path dir_A/home/username/ax/bups/hostname/dropbox/0rolling/Dropbox/.emacs.d/packages/gnupg/S.gpg-agent  has unknown file type)
```

---

### my manual checking with fishshell

I used multi-selection in my text-editor to extract the bits like:
"`(path [this bit] has unknown file type)`"
(made sure to escape any `'` chars in the paths)
so I could iterate over them like
(from within the dir containing `dir_A` and `dir_B`):

```
 # personal functions used
  # bbl
    function bbl --description 'big block lines'
      set -l bb $argv
      if test "$bb"
        for l in (string trim $bb)
          string trim $l
        end
      else
        while read -l l
          set l (string trim $l)
          test "$l"
          and echo $l
        end
      end
    end
  # p (pretty print feedback thing)
    function p
      if test -n "$argv"
            echo -n (set color $fish_color_comment) '#$ ' (set_color normal)
            string escape --style script  --  $argv    |string join " "  | fish_indent --ansi -i
      else
          while read -l x
            echo -n (set color $fish_color_comment) '#$ ' (set_color normal)
            string escape --style script  --  $x       |string join " "  | fish_indent --ansi -i
          end
      end
    end


 # actually doing it
  for path in (  
    bbl '  
      dir_A/dev/console  
      dir_A/dev/core  
      dir_A/dev/full  
      dir_A/dev/hda  
      dir_A/dev/hda1  
      dir_A/dev/hda10  
      dir_A/dev/hda11  
      dir_A/dev/hda12  
      dir_A/dev/hda13  
      dir_A/dev/hda14  
      dir_A/dev/hda15  
      dir_A/dev/hda16  
      dir_A/dev/hda17  
      dir_A/dev/hda18  
      dir_A/dev/hda19  
      dir_A/dev/hda2  
      dir_A/dev/input/event0  
      dir_A/dev/input/event1  
      dir_A/dev/input/event10  
      dir_A/dev/input/event11  
      dir_A/dev/input/event12  
      dir_A/dev/input/event13  
      dir_A/dev/input/event14  
      dir_A/dev/input/event15  
      dir_A/dev/input/event16  
      dir_A/dev/input/event17  
      dir_A/dev/input/event18  
      dir_A/dev/input/event19  
      dir_A/dev/input/js0  
      dir_A/dev/input/js1  
      dir_A/dev/input/js10  
      dir_A/dev/input/js11  
      dir_A/dev/input/js12  
      dir_A/dev/input/js13  
      dir_A/dev/input/js14  
      dir_A/dev/input/js15  
      dir_A/dev/input/js16  
      dir_A/dev/input/js17  
      dir_A/dev/input/js18  
      dir_A/dev/input/js19  
      dir_A/dev/input/keyboard  
      dir_A/dev/input/mice  
      dir_A/dev/input/mouse  
      dir_A/dev/input/mouse0  
      dir_A/dev/input/mouse1  
      dir_A/dev/input/mouse10  
      dir_A/dev/input/mouse11  
      dir_A/dev/input/mouse12  
      dir_A/dev/input/mouse13  
      dir_A/dev/input/mouse14  
      dir_A/dev/input/mouse15  
      dir_A/dev/input/mouse16  
      dir_A/dev/input/mouse17  
      dir_A/dev/input/mouse18  
      dir_A/dev/input/mouse19  
      dir_A/dev/input/uinput  
      dir_A/dev/mem  
      dir_A/dev/null  
      dir_A/dev/port  
      dir_A/dev/ptmx  
      dir_A/dev/random  
      dir_A/dev/sda  
      dir_A/dev/sda1  
      dir_A/dev/sda10  
      dir_A/dev/sda11  
      dir_A/dev/sda12  
      dir_A/dev/sda13  
      dir_A/dev/sda14  
      dir_A/dev/sda15  
      dir_A/dev/tty  
      dir_A/dev/tty0  
      dir_A/dev/tty1  
      dir_A/dev/tty10  
      dir_A/dev/tty11  
      dir_A/dev/tty12  
      dir_A/dev/tty13  
      dir_A/dev/tty14  
      dir_A/dev/tty15  
      dir_A/dev/tty16  
      dir_A/dev/tty17  
      dir_A/dev/tty18  
      dir_A/dev/tty19  
      dir_A/dev/urandom  
      dir_A/dev/zero  
      dir_A/tmp/runtime-username/pulse/native  
      dir_A/var/guix/daemon-socket/socket  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/anvil  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/bounce  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/defer  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/discard  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/error  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/lmtp  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/local  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/proxymap  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/proxywrite  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/relay  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/retry  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/rewrite  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/scache  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/smtp  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/tlsmgr  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/trace  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/verify  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/private/virtual  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/public/cleanup  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/public/flush  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/public/pickup  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/public/postlog  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/public/qmgr  
      dir_A/var/spool/postfix/public/showq  
      dir_A/var/tmp/audacity-username/.audacity.sock  
      dir_A/home/username/.cache/fontforge/python-socket  
      dir_A/home/username/.cache/keyring-70EDPZ/control  
      dir_A/home/username/.copy/copyagent-overlay.socket  
      dir_A/home/username/.dropbox/command_socket  
      dir_A/home/username/.dropbox/iface_socket  
      dir_A/home/username/.local/share/parcellite/fifo_c  
      dir_A/home/username/.local/share/parcellite/fifo_cmd  
      dir_A/home/username/.local/share/parcellite/fifo_p  
      dir_A/home/username/.steam/steam.pipe  
      dir_A/home/username/Dropbox/.emacs.d/packages/gnupg/S.gpg-agent  
      dir_A/home/username/ax/bups/hostname/dropbox/0rolling/Dropbox/.emacs.d/packages/gnupg/S.gpg-agent  
    '  
  )  
    #  
      set -l path_A .dir_A/$path  
      set -l path_B .dir_B/$path

    # `sudo diff` doesn't work for some reason (permission still denied even with sudo). I guess a weird edgecase bug in diff.  
      # p sudo diff $path_A $path_B  
      #   sudo diff $path_A $path_B  
      # or breakpoint

    #  
      for x in $path_A $path_B  
        p sudo test -e $x  
          sudo test -e $x  
        or breakpoint

        set -l size (sudo stat -c %s $x) # sudo prolly not needed?  
        p test $size = "0"  
          test $size = "0"  
        or breakpoint  
      end  
  end
```

---

---

So my my two backups `dir_A` and `dir_B` really are the same.

(And I'll check later that all those weird files really *are* size zero on in original source.)

((I've got so much more disaster recovery stuff to slog through, so I guess I'm done with *this* for now...))